# How do i keep looping the same my program so the user can input as much as they want?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, input

So i'm very new to python, i'm trying to create a program where the user can input a music chord between the range a - g and then receive back the information about that chord e.g. what notes make that chord. What i'm stuck with is letting the user find out about another chord without needing to restart the program. So I want to be able to have the input question again once they've done it already.

I haven't really tried much as I don't know where to start.

```
chord = input('What chord would you like to find out about? (A-G) ')
if chord.upper() == 'D':
    print(f"The D chord is made up of three notes: {d_chord}")
elif chord.upper() == 'G':
    print(f"The G chord is made up of three notes: {g_chord}")
```

So basically, when the user finishes their conversion, I want it to loop back to the top so they can again without restarting the program

Comment: follow https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: That was my second programming question, happened about 20 years ago, back in the school times. First one was "In turbo pascal, how to write calculator, so that user can input a, b, and action(+-*/), and it will print calculation result"? Of course, there was no stackoverflow, and very few people around me were actually interested on the topic..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what *you've* already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code into an infinite `while` loop:

```
while True:
    chord = input('What chord would you like to find out about? (A-G) ')
    if chord.upper() == 'D':
        print(f"The D chord is made up of three notes: {d_chord}")
    elif chord.upper() == 'G':
        print(f"The G chord is made up of three notes: {g_chord}")
```

If you only want to run it a specific number of times, you can use a `for` loop with a `range`:

```
for i in range(0,5): # loop will run 5 times
    chord = input('What chord would you like to find out about? (A-G) ')
    if chord.upper() == 'D':
        print(f"The D chord is made up of three notes: {d_chord}")
    elif chord.upper() == 'G':
        print(f"The G chord is made up of three notes: {g_chord}")
```

Comment: Thanks, helped alot!